# Dual monitors not working on Dell xps 13 9350 with Ubuntu 18

Tags: dual-boot, multiple-monitors, display, dell

Recently I installed Ubuntu 18.04.2 along side windows on my xps. I use a thunderbolt to HDMI to connect to a second display. When I boot into windows both displays work, but on Ubuntu my monitor does not detect a signal. When I go to setting to look at the devices/ display it shows my monitor as if it was connected. Not sure how to go about troubleshooting

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
sudo apt install bolt
```

Ensure you have all of the [drivers available to you](https://www.dell.com/support/home/uk/en/ukbsdt1/product-support/product/xps-13-9350-laptop/drivers) (there is an operating system drop down)

Comment: Okay I was able to see it was the newest version for thunderbolt